# Is there a Performance Difference of Non-Parallel Async Loop vs Sync Loop in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, async-await

I refactored JavaScript code for Node.js (v10.13.0) which was previously synchronous into asynchronous code using async/await. What I noticed afterwards was a performance degradation of ~3x slower program execution time.

Is there a performance penalty when transforming a chain of synchronous function calls into asynchronous function calls?

**Simplified Example**

*Changing synchronous code*

```
function fn1() {  
   return 1;
}

function fn2() { 
   return fn1();
}

(function() {
  const result = fn2();
})();
```

*into asynchronous code:*

```
async function fn1() {  
   return 1;
}

async function fn2() { 
   return await fn1();
}

(async function() {
   const result = await fn2();
})();
```

Is there any event-loop-magic which could make the latter code slower in a Node.js webapp?

Comment: All this is doing is creating unnecessary Promises with the `async` functions and changing the order of execution a bit. You don't make synchronous code asynchronous like this.

Comment: `async` and `await` are syntactic sugar. The native implementation will generate heaps of extra code (generator function) that will keep track of where to move next when an async operation completes. This adds overhead and will slow down performance.

Comment: @MarkMeyer to clarify the use case: in my scenario an async database fetch operation must be implemented into fn1() and the callers of fn1() must wait for the result to be returned. That is why I must somehow change functions in the calling chain like fn2(). I am not trying to make something asynchronous without reason. :)
Would it be more efficient to pass a callback function?

Comment: @MartinLöper If you're not `await`ing anything, then remove the `async` declaration. I.e. if `fn(1)` is your async db call, you can elide the call and directly return the `Promise` if you **DON'T** have to do anything with the result after the db call returns. This means you can then change `fn2()` not to be `async` either and directly return `fn1()`. The only place where you need `async` keyword then, is when you want to get the result from async call and that is in your IIFE.

Comment: It would seem quite obvious that adding unnecessary overhead to functions does slow them down. Is this really unexpected? And why did you "*refactor code which was previously synchronous into asynchronous code*" in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi Good question! I wanted a pure getter function to (conditionally) make a database call. Lets say 1 out of 1000 calls is a database call. The remainder returns a value from memory. The function was called a dozen of times as part of a line sweep algorithm, which by design is a big for loop. The function that became asynchronous was called very deep in the call stack because it was some utility function. I had to make all function in the call chain asynchronous for them to be able to call that utility function. It resulted in a drastic slowdown which was the motivation behind this SO post

Comment: @MartinLöper A getter, especially one you call "pure", should definitely not make a database call. Load the data upfront, then run your algorithm on it.

Comment: You are definitely right that you should not write code like that. I am just curious what happens if you do it nonetheless. It's interesting that this post lead to a discussion  what JS and the JIT compiler is supposed to do and what is part of the developer's responsibility. Really appreciate your opinions on this topic guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more advanced benchmark that calculates Fibonacci series with either a synchronous or async function:

```
async function benchmark(M = 1000000, N = 100) {
    function fibonacci_sync(num) {
        let a = 1, b = 0, temp
        while (num >= 0) {
            temp = a; a = a + b; b = temp; num--
        }
        return b
    }
    async function fibonacci_async(num) {
        let a = 1, b = 0, temp
        while (num >= 0) {
            temp = a; a = a + b; b = temp; num--
        }
        return b
    }
    timeitSync  ('sync',  M,       () => {for(let i = 0; i < N; i++) fibonacci_sync(i)})
    await timeit('async', M, async () => {for(let i = 0; i < N; i++) await fibonacci_async(i)})
}
```

Sample execution times in node.js - async turns out to be **2.8x slower**:

```
sync:    4.753s
async:  13.359s
```

With a larger `M`, but smaller `N = 10` instead of N=100 (shorter calculation, so awaits have bigger impact), the async function becomes **14.5x slower** (ooops!!):

```
sync:   0.499s
async:  7.258s
```

This is on Node v16.13.1. The benchmark was inspired by this post:
https://madelinemiller.dev/blog/javascript-promise-overhead/

For the sake of completeness, here are the `timeit` functions as used above:

```
async function timeit(label, repeat, fun) {
    console.time(label)
    for (let i = 0; i < repeat; i++) await fun()
    console.timeEnd(label)
}
function timeitSync(label, repeat, fun) {
    console.time(label)
    for (let i = 0; i < repeat; i++) fun()
    console.timeEnd(label)
}
```

When measuring `fibonacci_sync` with `async timeit` instead of `timeitSync`, the execution time grows from `0.499s` to `1.2s` in the last example, which is another confirmation that `async` brings a lot of slowdown.

So, yes, indeed, asynchronous calls may introduce a HUGE decline in performance, even of an order of magnitude. Each call must go through an event queue, whose management seems to create a substantial overhead. This definitely should be taken into account when implementing code that's densely packed with async functions.

Given how "infectious" the `async` paradigm is - with a single low-level function being async, all its callers up the tree must be async too - I'd be glad that JS introduces optimizations to allow `await...` be executed instantly in some (most) cases rather than being pushed to a queue again and again every couple of instructions. This could benefit all the scenarios where `await` is wrapped up in a conditional and rarely needs to actually stop the function, but still requires the function be declared as "async", no matter how often the "await" is being reached.

Comment: "*Each call must go through an event queue*" - it's not function calls, it's resumptions of the `await`ing code after promise resolution that go through the microtask queue. "*JS introduces optimizations to allow `await...` be executed instantly in some (most) cases*" - no, it doesn't, and never will. That `await` expressions guarantee asynchrony (just like the `.then()` calls that they are syntactic sugar for) is an important feature of async functions.

Comment: The key takeaway from [the article that you linked](https://madelinemiller.dev/blog/javascript-promise-overhead/): "*The simplest solution here is to perform data fetching or other asynchronous operations closer to the application's root and pass the resulting data down. Often program structures that involve deep-nested async/await paths exhibit poor separation of concerns. Ideally, a single system should not load and use data; instead, it should receive the data from another system that loads it. This structure also has the added benefit of being much more testable.*"

Comment: @Bergi: in some cases, the fact that *await expressions guarantee asynchrony...* is a bug, not a feature - the benchmark above tells why. What a programmer usually wants to achieve with "await" is to **allow**, not **enforce**, asynchrony in that particular place. It should be the job of an interpreter and JIT compiler to decide whether deferring execution is desirable in a given moment or not - this kind of optimizations is exactly what a JIT compiler is for. No, I don't think that making programmers responsible for these optimizations will help them build better software.

Comment: Interesting discussion about what the JS engine should or should not do, guys! I totally did not intend to enforce asynchronous behaviour when I extended our codebase. I just wanted to allow asynchrony for a deeply nested method that was called a dozen of time because of some for loop.